# How to remove duplicate values from exploded comma-separated array from string?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$NoteKey = ",";

(loop) if ... then{
    $NoteKey .= "</td><td>";
    $NoteKey .= $val2;
    $NoteKey .= "</td><td>";
    $NoteKey .= $val3;
    $NoteKey .= "</td><td>";
    $NoteKey .= "</td></tr>";
    $NoteKey .= ",";
}

$NoteKey_trim = trim($NoteKey, ",");
$NoteKey_clean = explode(",",$NoteKey_trim);
$NoteKey_unique = array_unique($NoteKey_clean);
```

The issue is that nothing is outputting ... it works up until `$NoteKey_clean` then no output ...

Comment: Don't put html tags in your array, just put your values into the array, and when you need to print it then put the values between the tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
$NoteKey_trim = trim($NoteKey, ",");// delete ","
$NoteKey_clean = explode(",",$NoteKey_trim); // $NoteKey_trim don't have ","  
//explode can't find ","
$NoteKey_unique = array_unique($NoteKey_clean);
$NoteKey_trim = trim($NoteKey);

if(strpos(",",$NoteKey_trim)!==false){  // $NoteKey_trim has "," 
  $NoteKey_clean = explode(",",$NoteKey_trim);
  $NoteKey_unique = array_unique($NoteKey_clean);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] functions= commaSeperatedString.split(",");

        List<String> uniqueFunctions = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String function : functions) {
            if ( !uniqueFunctions.contains(function.trim())) {
                uniqueFunctions.add(function.trim());
            }
        }
        return String.join(",",uniqueFunctions);
```